# Zend Framework 1.10: disableLayout and form tags

Tags: forms, zend-framework

I'm working on an action that displays a form in the view page. This is the content of the view (let's call it form.phtm):

```
<?php echo $this->form; ?>
```

This view is used both to show a complete page with its header, content and footer, or just the content, to be displayed in a reveal panel.

Header and footer are provided by the layout files, and the content is the line of code above. So, when it is meant to be displayed in the reveal panel, I specify it to the action by passing an '`ajax = true`' parameter, and the action disables the layout so that only the content is output.

All of that looks fine, but when trying to submit the form from the reveal panel, it doesn't work.

When inspecting the markup, I realize that the form open and close tags don't exist, though all the fields and buttons are displayed. This only happens after calling `disableLayout()` (i.e. in the full version of the page the full form is output).

I think my question can be summed up as "What is the diference between echo `$this->form` with the layout enabled and the same code with the layout disabled"?

P.S. I know I can manually echo the form tags and elements, I just want to know if there is an easier/more elegant way to display the whole form without having to worry about whether it is being called via ajax.

Edit 17/05/2015: I was using the word "label" but I meant "tag" (already corrected).

Comment: So, what you are looking for is to just return a rendered form through an ajax call?

Comment: Yes, and it is working almost fine. Only the <form> and </form> tags aren't rendered when printing the form. Actually, I just want to know if that is the expected behaviour when the layout is disabled and the reasoning behind this.

Comment: Well, it seems it has nothing to do with ZF since even typing the form tags myself they dont appear in the markup. Checking if it is related to a wrong HTML structure, like suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477655/chrome-does-not-render-form-tag-ff-does

Comment: Make sure you look at the raw html output, aka Page Source, and not any rendered HTML in like firebug or Chrome's Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad.

Because of the way I was including the parts of my document, the mentioned form ended up being nested inside another form, and thus Chrome removed the inner form tags.

This post gave me the lead:
 [tag is not shown when created with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243034/form-tag-is-not-shown-when-created-with-php)